# What should I do to add data/values/objects to an initializer list and later send it to a constructor?

Tags: c++11, initialization, initializer-list

So I wanted to practice my skills of using smart pointers. I created a template of class (one-linked list) that has constructor like:

```
template <class Type> 
class list
  {
          //...
   public:
          list( std::initializer_list < Type > initlist ) { ... }

          //...
    };
```

In main-function I want to construct initializer list and pass it to the class constructor as one thing (smth like this, I think it can be possible but I don't know how to do):

```
typedef int Type;

int main ()
{
   //...
   size_t count; // to know How many elements initlist will have
   std :: initializer_list < Type > initlist;

   cout << "Enter, please, count of elements and their values\n";
   cin >> count;

   Type temp_data;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
        cin >> temp_data; //user input data and program add it to list
        initlist.push_back( temp_data ); 
 // it's wrong. But I found no analogue of "push_back" in std :: initializer_list
 // I used push_back to explain what I want to do
     }

   // ... do stuff

   // now I want to pass it to the class object
   list < Type > mylist ( initlist ); // or mylist = initlist, or mylist{initlist}

}
```

I could do smth like below but if I don't know how many and what elements will be input by user then what I should do:

```
list <Type> mylist {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

So, What should I do to write it correctly? Maybe somebody has an idea.
Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of `std::initializer_list<T>` is to be able to initialize a container when you know all the elements you want to put in it. If you _don't_ know all the elements you want to put in it then don't use `std::initializer_list`, insert elements one-by-one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually in C++ containers provide both an `std::initializer_list` constructor and a constructor that takes two iterators (of any given size) and copies the content of that "range" into the container.

So for example your class could have something like this:

```
template <class Type> 
class list {
    //...
public:
    list(std::initializer_list<Type> initlist) { ... }

    template<typename It>
    list(It begin, It end) { ... }

    //...
};
```

In the standard library `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::forward_list`, `std::deque` and other containers all support those.

This is done so that if a user knows the elements he/she wants to insert into the container at the moment the container is created he/she uses the `std::initializer_list` overload. Otherwise if he/she has some other dynamically built container, he can just import the elements in your container.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a dynamically-sized `std::initializer_list`. That class is supposed to be lightweight and simple.

You could instead implement `push_back` or `push_front` for your `list` class and build it up incrementally.

The analogue to your current idea would be to build up a `std::vector` or similar, then provide a constructor which takes an iterator range to copy from that container.